# Remove non domain user from local admins powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I remove non domain user `AdminDE` from local admins?

He appears in administrators like this: `pcname\AdminDE`. I tried but did not work: `Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "pcname\AdminDE"`

I get an error: `Remove-LocalGroupMember : Principal pcname\AdminDE was not found.`

Comment: Your error message shows a different username than the command you're running?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question for simplicity purposes. Just changed the naming conventions to make it easier to read, now everything matches.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the user account with `Get-LocalUser 'AdminDE'` and then passing that to `Remove-LocalGroupMember`?

Comment: I just tried it, still does not want to work as expected.

Comment: Sounds like the user is either not local, or doesn't have the name you expect. Do you see the user account in the output from `Get-LocalUser` (run the command without specifying the user name)?

Comment: After additional details provided from @MathiasR.Jessen, I managed to get it working like this: `Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member AdminDE`. Which is strange to be honest, but tried few times and it worked.

Comment: Add that as an answer (textbox below) then - answering your own questions is totally fine :-)

Comment: Piping it should’ve worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional points, I figured this is what worked for me (strangely enough):

```
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member AdminDE
```

Thank You Mathias R. Jessen.